# Automatically launch "call" dialog on iOS mobile devices when clicking an action button

Tags: lightning, ios, phone

A client of mine is attempting to use an Action Button on a Salesforce record page trigger a phone call to a relevant phone number. The button merely says "Call." I have gotten this functionality to work in multiple ways Desktop and Android: e.g., by executing a Javascript click on an invisible anchor tag, or by simply using `e.force:navigateToURL`.

These methods do not work on iOS, however. My research has found that in order to get this to work on iOS, I would have to set window.location.href to "tel://{phoneNumber}". Yet, the Lightning Locker Service SecureWindow object only allows for navigation to URLs that are http, https, or mailto. Tel: is not possible.

I was wondering if anyone had an idea of how I can make this work without insisting that my client changes their app design. They would really like to see this feature come to fruition if at all possible.

Here is the relevant anchor tag in the controller:

```
<a class="external" target="_system" id="callme" tabindex="0" onfocus="{!c.startCall}" href="{!'tel://'+ v.simpleRecord.Click_to_Call_Phone__c}">{!v.simpleRecord.Click_to_Call_Phone__c}</a>
```

And the Javascript code we are using today (which works on desktop and Android):

```
      const anchor = event.target;
      const urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");

      urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": 'tel://' + anchor.innerText
      });
      
      urlEvent.fire();
```